# Excel formula for changing text into minutes

Tags: microsoft-excel

When extracting data from a Database, I am receiving the duration of time in a text format.

What formula do I need to change all the text into number of minutes so I can add rows up to get a total time?

Assume all text below is in a single column:

```
5 hours, 48 minutes 
11 minutes  
28 minutes  
12 minutes
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you tell us what you've already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your entries are always of one of the following three formats:

1) **x hours, y minutes**; 2) **x hours**; 3) **y minutes**

and no other, then:

`=0+SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REPT("0:",1-COUNTIF(A1,"*hour*"))&A1,"hours",":"),"minutes",""),",","")`

where the cells in which these formulas are contained should be formatted as **[h]:mm**

and can then be summed as required.